# How to copy linked content files using .NET Core csproj?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core, csproj, msbuild-task

I'm referencing [this article](http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx) in an attempt to copy linked files before each build:

```
<Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" 
          DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)" 
          SkipUnchangedFiles='true' 
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles='true' 
          Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
 </Target>
```

This doesn't appear to work for the new .NET Core csproj tooling.  What would be an equivalent target that does?

**EDIT: Example csproj content**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Features>IOperation</Features>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Template</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\MyRefProject\ChangeTypes.cs" Link="ChangeTypes.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\MyRefProject\Parser.cs" Link="Parser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\MyRefProject\Calculator.cs" Link="Calculator.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\MyRefProject\Converter.cs" Link="Converter.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Do you want to copy the content to the local project development folder or the output directory? if local project folder: in sdk-based csproj this could cause duplicate output paths errors when the next run auto-detects the files and the relative path is the same as the link

Comment: I'd like to copy to the local project dev folder.  I did implement Marc's recommendation below, which seems to work.  If there were to be issues, would you expect them to be intermittent?

Comment: I should clarify - I'd like to copy the files from the project folder in which they actually reside to the project folder in which they are linked.  My reason for doing this is that I'm using DocFx to generate docs for the project in which they are linked, but not the other.

Comment: it could cause some conflicts if the items are set to copy to the output directory (since both the link metadata and the relative path of the items in the project folder would result in the same output path)

Answer (score 4):

A `Condition` should be specified at the `Target` level but this won't help in this scenario because you can't use an elements metadata as a condition.

You also need to provide an output path. Your example will only copy linked content into the project's directory, not it's output directory.

```
<Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
<Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" 
        DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)\%(Content.Link)" 
        SkipUnchangedFiles="true" 
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

The documentation for the `Copy` task can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task).

I tested this using Visual Studio 2017 with two simple console projects. The second project included a couple of text files. The first project also references these files via content links. This is the `.csproj` file from the first project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="..\Project2\ReadMeFirst.txt" Link="ReadMeFirst.txt" />
        <Content Include="..\Project2\ReadMeSecond.txt" Link="ReadMeSecond.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" 
            DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)\%(Content.Link)" 
            SkipUnchangedFiles="true" 
            OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I can do this, and it works.  However, I've ended up created a SourceFiles item collection to which I manually add the linked files.  The example up top appears to automatically detect all the linked files and copy them over, without having to update the .csproj each time a linked file is added.  That's the specific capability I'm interested in - do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: Doh, my bad. I just realized I this only worked for me because I only had 1 linked file when I tested. Could you provide a copy of your .csproj? I have a fixed but want to make sure it actually works with your setup.

Comment: No worries.  I've added the sanitized .csproj content in my edit.